# WCF - In streaming endpoints, do all operation contracts require a stream as a return or parameter for the contract to work?

Tags: wcf

I wondering if in the same endpoint, which has been set to streamed transport mode, is it required to have all operation contracts in this service to have a stream in the parameter or as the return type for this service to work?

In short: Can streamed enabled endpoint contain operation contracts that do not have stream as a parameter or as a return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can keep the same contract even if you use an stream endpoint, it doesn't matter if it contains the stream as a return type or parameter.

For it to work you need to change some of the members of the contract to the headers.

```
[MessageContract]
public class MyContract
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm using this technique but so far in my tests it appears that it is still buffering since I'm not getting any results at my client until the stream on the server is completed.

Answer (score 2):

Check the MSDN docs on [Streaming Message Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx):

> **Restrictions on Streamed Transfers**
>
> Using the streamed transfer mode
>   causes the run time to enforce
>   additional restrictions.
>
> **Operations that occur across a
>   streamed transport can have a contract
>   with at most one input or output
>   parameter. That parameter corresponds
>   to the entire body of the message and
>   must be a Message, a derived type of
>   Stream, or an IXmlSerializable
>   implementation.** Having a return value
>   for an operation is equivalent to
>   having an output parameter.

So if you have a service contract that will be exposed over an endpoint with streaming enabled, **all** operations on that contract must be using `Message`, or `Stream` as their single parameter.